# Login authentication with finger print in mobile application

Tags: fingerprint, mobile-application

i am new to fingerprint authentication for mobile application login in both iOS and android. Would like know how does it work when i want to authenticate my user to login to the application with the fingerprint which had been stored in their phone. Am i allow to do so?

thank you.